# react native reselect error selector creators except all input

Tags: react-native, redux, expo, reselect

what I do am wrong ?

reselect.js

```
import { createSelector } from 'reselect';

const createCollection = state => state.createCollection;

export const getCollectionName = createSelector(
  createCollection,
  (el) => el
);
```

if I only import the file, then I get this error:

```
Error: Selector creators expect all input-selectors to be functions, instead received the following types: [undefined]
```

Comment: Can you log what `state.createCollection` is as I believe that’s undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Must be an import problem, you have no error in the code you provided:

```js
const { createSelector } = Reselect;

const state = {};
const createCollection = state => state.createCollection;

const getCollectionName = createSelector(
  createCollection,
  (el) => el
);
console.log(getCollectionName(state))
console.log(
  'also works:'
  ,getCollectionName(
    {createCollection:'hello world'}
  )
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/reselect/4.0.0/reselect.min.js"></script>
```

You should probably log what `createCollection` is before using it in `createSelector`.

You should prefix your selectors with `select` so your future self and other members of your team can recognise the selectors: `selectCreateCollection` and `selectCollectionName`